# ZedGraph - How to fill the area between two curves?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I've two curves. One of them is above the another. I've also set the `IsSmooth` to `true` (the lines are bent at the corners).
I want to fill the area between the top and bottom curve…

What's the best method to do so?
I think using PolyObj is not a good idea because I have to store the points separately, and the final filled area is not smooth like the lines.

Here is a sample:
[image: an example of two smooth curves]